# Date condition not yielding any results in MySQL query

Tags: mysql, sqldatetime

I have a table like this:

```
> desc my_tab

+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| host  | varchar(128) | NO   |     |         |       |
| state | varchar(128) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| cdt   | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| mdt   | timestamp    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

There are many rows with date >= '31-jan-2018 00:00:00'.  If I run `select * from my_tab` I do see them.  However, when I run this query:

```
select * from my_tab where cdt >= '31-jan-2018 00:00:00'
```

I get no results.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That doesn't *look* like a datetime !?!?!?! '2018-01-31 00:00:00' looks like a datetime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-types.html

> Although MySQL tries to interpret values in several formats, date parts must always be given in year-month-day order (for example, '98-09-04'), rather than in the month-day-year or day-month-year orders commonly used elsewhere (for example, '09-04-98', '04-09-98').

Comment: I'm sure this is a common mistake for SQL users, and the question has come up many times on Stack Overflow, but I'm just going to post this answer instead of taking the time to find one of the past duplicates. Someone else can do that.